# Appending all array items only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to output the HTML of all the selected options from a dropdown list in a new div. However, everytime I select a new checkbox, my container gets updated with the selected value (like its supposed to), but it also appends every previously selected value from the dropdown list. And so on, and so on. How do I output the checkboxes HTML only once?

Heres my JS code:

```
let emptyArr = [];
$('.dropdown-select-container').find("option:selected").each(function(){
    emptyArr.push($(this).html());
});

for (i in emptyArr) {
  let outputResult = "<div class='arr-item'>" + emptyArr[i] + "</div>"
  $("#container").append(outputResult);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you have an `option` with no `select`, and have `// List of checkboxes` inside of it? Why would there be checkboxes in an `option`?

Comment: I apologize but I skipped the HTML part. I wanted the focus to be more on the jquery.

Comment: ^ jQuery won't work as expected if you have invalid HTML markup.

Comment: @BirdMars: When it comes to performing DOM selection and mutations, the actual structure you're working with is necessary to fully understand what's going on.

Comment: My question is purely JS oriented: why every loop I get the full array of elements instead of only the `[i]` or current itteration.

Comment: a jsfiddle or similar would help.

Comment: And hey, you're appending over and over -- you never empty the div of its existing contents. When you first start handling the loop, you probably want to wipe the container clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using jQuery's `append`, your `#container` will always ***append*** (aka add) the contents of `outputResult` as opposed to replacing the contents of `#container`. Instead, you should use the `html` function to empty the contents of `#container` and replace the contents with `outputResult` like so:

```
$("#container").html(outputResult);
```

Comment: dad-gum it, I was getting there. Heh. Nicely said, @christiansantos.

Answer (score 1):

Given incomplete data, we do what we can. In future, it's always easier to diagnose what you're trying to do with complete information.

However, this is all overkill. Re-reading your post, you asked why you are getting a, then aab, then aababc, when you add more checks or whatever. The simple answer is because you're appending more and more stuff into the div, but you never remove what's already there. Before you start appending, simply call empty() on that container div. See below to see what I mean.

```js
$(".dropdown-select-container").on("change", function() {

    var emptyArr = [];
    // Go through the select, find all selected options.
  $('.dropdown-select-container').find(":selected").each(function() {
    emptyArr.push($(this).html());
  });
  // remove all current content.
  $("#container").empty();
  
  // go through the array line by line,
  //  and create a div for each.
  for (var i = 0; i < emptyArr.length; i++) {
  console.log(emptyArr);
    var outputResult = "<div class='arr-item'>" + emptyArr[i] + "</div>"
    $("#container").append(outputResult);
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>

<label>Selection list</label>

<select class="dropdown-select-container" multiple>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
  <option value="CA">California</option>
  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
  <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
  <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
  <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
  <option value="FL">Florida</option>
  <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
  <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
  <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
  <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
  <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
  <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
  <option value="ME">Maine</option>
  <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
  <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
  <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
  <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
  <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
  <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
  <option value="MT">Montana</option>
  <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
  <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
  <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
  <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
  <option value="NY">New York</option>
  <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
  <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
  <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
  <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
  <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
  <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
  <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
  <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
  <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
  <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
  <option value="TX">Texas</option>
  <option value="UT">Utah</option>
  <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
  <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
  <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```